# Multiple sequence alignment

Tags: javascript, alignment, sequence, dna-sequence

I know it may seem kind of strange but I was wondering if anybody has ever seen some javascript code for the [multiple sequence alignment problem](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment). If not (as I suppose) also some **easily portable** code (i.e. I need no kitchen sink) will do. Keep in mind that I won't be aligning more than 4-5 sequences less than 100-200 symbols long.

Note: I know javascript is not really the best choice for this kind of things. Trust me, there's a good reason why I have to do it in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I found is just a [pairwise sequence alignment algorithm](http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/pairwise_align_dna.html). I turned it into something that would do MSA but it's definitely too slow to be usable for anything longer than a hundred symbols.

Answer (score 1):

http://biostar.stackexchange.com/